# How to know if user landed on page by URL or by navigating through modules?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have a React SPA where if user can land on a module using navigation and by direct link. I want to know if user landed on the page using link or navigated the hierarchy in order to reach the page. Is there a way to achieve this?

So far I have tried this code.

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("yourdomain.com")==-1) {
 console.log("first page")
}
```

but as I have a SPA, page never changes and it always says first page.

Comment: what is your implementation for client-side routing? perhaps you can traverse the history

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
document.write(document.referrer);
```

Comment: This does not help, as it just prints the referrer and does nothing else.

Comment: I thinks he meant that you can use document.referrer for knowing the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. This adds click listener on the body. The `requestAnimationFrame()` method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. In the callback function, we check if something is changed in URL then `console.log()`

```
let url = location.href;
document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      if(url!==location.href){
         console.log(location.href)
          url = location.href;
      }
    });
}, true);
```

You can read more

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame